# Scala 'this' and 'self' not working in simple App

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

New to scala (using version 2.12.1) obviously from the title. I'm writing my first app in IntelliJ. I've read about the Scala equivalent in Java to `this`. I've tried `this`, `self`, `classOf[]` and IntelliJ is complaining and the code is not compiling even if I ignore IntelliJ. Here's what I have:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger

object Main extends App {
  val logger = Logger[Main] 
}
```

Logger package is importing correctly in SBT. However it cannot resolve the symbol `Main`. I tried sticking it in a package to make it less ubiquitous and then doing something like `Logger[me.justin.Main]` but that also doesn't work.

I also thought maybe extending App was causing some problems but I think that's fixed in the scala version I'm using? Maybe it's not even applicable?

I'm all Googled out. Help please!

Comment: what is `App`??

Comment: Thats a scala trait that allows you to make the `Main` object runnable. It's basically says this object has a main method like in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting tripped up by how Scala's objects work. Let's say we had a class `Foo` and a companion object for same:

```
class Foo

object Foo
```

If we wanted a logger for the class, we'd do the obvious thing:

```
val logger = Logger[Foo] // `Foo` here is the type of the class.
```

But what if we wanted to refer to the type of the object? We have to disambiguate from the type of the class. The answer is to use the special `type` member on the object:

```
val logger = Logger[Foo.type] // `Foo.type` here is the type of the object.
```

So in your case:

```
val logger = Logger[Main.type]
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to have to read about the differences in a class and an object.